# How do I add a vector to another holding the first vector constant?

Tags: r

How do I add a vector to another while keeping for the first vector constant? For example if I had `c(1, 2, 3) + 1`. I would get 2, 3, 4. If I wanted to scale this up to say + 1, and + 2, what could I do to get

```
2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5
```

Intuitively I wanted to `c(1, 2, 3) + c(1, 2)` but this does not work.

Comment: `outer(1:3, 1:2, FUN='+')` or `c(outer(1:3, 1:2, FUN='+'))`

Comment: Or `x <- 1:3; x + rep(1:2, each = length(x))`

Comment: One last quick question I sometimes have `seq_len(0)` which returns "integer(0)". Is there any elegant way I can do + 0 or just return the first vector or am I better off writing a conditional?

Comment: @John-Henry Do you need to change `1:2` to `0:2` ?

Comment: @markus I am using the function `seq_len(x)` to make the vector which basically does `1:x`. I am running into an issue when `x = 0` because it returns "integer(0)". Do you have any tips for this? It is a different question than I am asking in the thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning the comments into an answer we can use `outer` as @jogo showed

```
c(outer(1:3, 1:2, FUN='+'))
# [1] 2 3 4 3 4 5
```

Another option is `rep`

```
f <- function(x, y) {
  x + rep(y, each = length(x))
}

f(1:3, 1:2)
# [1] 2 3 4 3 4 5
```